# Como transformar um JSON que contém um array de objetos em uma lista de objetos?

Tags: json, array, mongodb

Boa noite. Tenho o seguinte JSON:

```
 {
  "_id": {
  "$oid": "3432fa43242"
 },
 "posts": [{
 "thread": {
    "uuid": "2911da",
    "url": "http://www.google.com",
    "site_full": "opiniaoenoticia.com.br",
    "site": "opiniaoenoticia.com.br",
    "site_section": "http://opiniaoenoticia.com.br/feed/",
    "site_categories": [],
    "section_title": "Opinião e Notícia",
    "title": "Veto a protestos contra Temer na Rio 2016 gera polêmica",
    "title_full": "Veto a protestos contra Temer na Rio 2016 gera polêmica",
    "published": "2016-08-08T18:07:00.000+03:00",
    "replies_count": 0,
    "participants_count": 1,
    "site_type": "news",
    "country": "BR",
    "spam_score": 0.0,
    "main_image": "",
    "performance_score": 0,
    "domain_rank": null,
    "social": {
        "facebook": {
            "likes": 0,
            "comments": 0,
            "shares": 0
        },
        "gplus": {
            "shares": 0
        },
        "pinterest": {
            "shares": 0
        },
        "linkedin": {
            "shares": 0
        },
        "stumbledupon": {
            "shares": 0
        }
    }
},
"uuid": "2931da",
"url": "http://3NXmoxXP9jWxZXABLjFrpB03",
"ord_in_thread": 0,
"author": "Melissa",
"published": "2016-08-08T18:07:00.000+03:00",
"title": "Veto a protestos contra Temer na Rio 2016 gera polêmica",
"text": "Início » Brasil » Veto a protestos contra Temer na Rio 2016 gera polêmica.",
"highlightText": "",
"highlightTitle": "",
"language": "portuguese",
"external_links": [],
"entities": {
    "persons": [],
    "organizations": [],
    "locations": []
},
"crawled": "2016-08-08T22:09:19.938+03:00"
}, {
 "thread": {...
```

Como transformar o array de objetos posts em uma lista de objetos? Estou com os dados salvos no MongoDB.

Obrigada.

Comment: O seu problema é com o JSON (trabalhando em php, javascript, .net, etc) ou com os dados armazenados no mongodb? Outra, o que você quer dizer com "lista de objetos"? O array já é uma lista de objetos.

Answer (score 0):

O php tem uma função específica para isso:

```
json_decode(string_json,boolean)
```

O segundo parâmetro diz respeito se na conversão você quer retornar um array associativo ou não.

Seu exemplo ficaria:

```
$json_retornado = '...' // Entre aspas simples
$objeto_php = json_encode($json_retornado)
```

Dessa forma terá um objeto php navegável na forma:

```
$objeto_php->_id->$oid
```